# Python and statistical analysis tutorials

Tags: regression, python, references, descriptive-statistics

I am slowly learning Python, and I am curious if anyone has come across some easy to follow tutorials or books explaining how to program simple to intermediate statistical methods, from basic descriptive tests to regression analysis and beyond.

Answer (score 3):

[Think Stats](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkstats/) is a free textbook using Python to teach statistical concepts.

Answer (score 2):

There have been a few tutorials at the SciPy conferences over the past summers. [Here's one](http://conference.scipy.org/scipy2013/tutorial_detail.php?id=109). There was also one on [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sf.net) in 2012.

Answer (score 1):

`Thinks Stats` is good to learn some basic statistical concepts, but I don't think you want to **do** statistics this way, that is without using numpy and scipy.

One introduction to doing statistics with python that I like is

http://work.thaslwanter.at/Stats/html/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new Stats text that I think is pretty good with many IPython Notebooks and a good Text http://work.thaslwanter.at/Stats/html/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check out O'Reilly's [Python for Data Analysis](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023784.do), written by Wes McKinney. I've heard very good things about it: comprehensive and easy to follow. Good luck!